# Why can't the data from the database be retrieved or updated?

Tags: java, mysql, japplet

Trying to read data  and update in my database but it seems to always give an exception. Why can't I read and update anything. I know that I have a connection with the database. Am I am fairly sure my SQL syntax is correct in my java code. The program/applet is not running in a browser be directly in eclipse,  so this should work fine.

Here is my code

```
public class Kreta1 extends JApplet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -6464646464646464646;//just some nrs

private Vector card;
private int menu_id;
private String name_dish,price,ingredients,recipe;
private Connectie con; 


 class Afhaalmenu1{

        private Connectie con;
        private int menu_id;
        private String name_dish,price,ingredients,recipe;
        private Vector card; 

        public Afhaalmenu1(){
             con= new Connectie();
             card=new Vector();
        }
        public Afhaalmenu1(int menu_id){
            this();
            this.menu_id=menu_id;
        }
            public Afhaalmenu1(int menu_id, String name_dish, String price,String ingredients, String recipe){
                this();
                this.menu_id=menu_id;
                this.name_dish=name_dish;
                this.price=price;
                this.ingredients=ingredients;
                this.recipe=recipe;

            }
            public void setName_dish (String ng){
                this.name_dish=ng;
            }
            public String getName_dish){
                return name_dish;
            }
            public void setPrice (String pr){
                this.price=pr;
            }
            public String getPrice(){
                return price;
            }
            public void setIngredients(String ingr){
                this.ingredients=ingr;
            }
            public String getIngredients(){
                return ingredients;
            }
            public void setRecipe(String rec){
                this.recipe=rec;
            }
            public String getRecipe(){
                return recipe;
            }
            public void setMenu_id(int I){
                this.menu_id=I;
            }
            public int getMenu_id(){
                return menu_id;
            }


        public void readCard(int menu_id){

            try{

                java.sql.Statement statement= con.connection.createStatement();
                this.menu_id=menu_id;

                String gget;

                gget="SELECT * FROM afhaalmenu WHERE menu_id= "+ this.menu_id;

                ResultSet rs= statement.executeQuery(gget);

                rs.next();

                this.menu_id=rs.getInt(1);
                this.name_dish=rs.getString(2);
                this.price= rs.getString(3);
                this.ingredients= rs.getString(4);
                this.recipe= rs.getString(5);
            System.out.println(this.menu_id);               


            }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println("did not read anything");
            }
        }

        public void updateCard(){

             try{

                 java.sql.Statement statement= con.connection.createStatement();   

                 String sset;
                 sset= "UPDATE afhaalmenu " + "SET name_dish = '" + name_dish + "', " + "price='" + this.price + "'," +
                 " ingredients='" + this.ingredients + "'," + "recipe='" + this.recipe+ "'"+ "WHERE afhaalmenu.menu_id = " + this.menu_id;          

                 statement.executeUpdate(sset);      
                 System.out.println();
             }catch(Exception e){
                 System.out.println("did not update anything");
             }     
        }

        public void writeCard(){
               try{
     java.sql.Statement statement =con.connection.createStatement();

                 String gget;

      gget=  "SELECT "+this.menu_id+" FROM afhaalmenu";


                ResultSet rs =statement.executeQuery(gget);
                rs.last();
                this.menu_id=(rs.getInt(1))+1;

            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.print("display error");
            con.displaySQLErrors(e);
            }
                            try{

                java.sql.Statement statement= con.connection.createStatement();

                String sset;

                sset= "INSERT INTO afhaalmenu(menu_id, name_dish, price, ingredients, recipe,) VALUES ('" + this.menu_id + "' ,'"+ this.name_dish + "', '"+ this.price +"','"+this.ingredients  + "','" + this.recipe + "');";  
                                    //System.out.println(sset);
                statement.executeUpdate(sset);
                System.out.println(sset);
            }catch (Exception e){

                System.out.println("error writing to database");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public Vector readAllCards(){

            try{

                java.sql.Statement statement= con.connection.createStatement();

                String gget;

                gget="SELECT FROM afhaalmenu; ";                                            
                ResultSet rs= statement.executeQuery(gget);

                while (rs.next()){
                    Vector vRow= new Vector();
                    for(int x=0;x<=3;x++){
                        vRow.addElement(rs.getString(x));
                }
                afhaalKaarten.add(vRow);
            }
            }catch(Exception e){
                //con.displaySQLErrors(e);                  
System.out.println("all cards can not be read");
            }

            return card;
        }
    }
        public Kreta1(){

    con= new Connectie();
    card= new Vector();


    }

public void init(){
    // gui stuff here
    Afhaalmenu1 afm= new Afhaalmenu1(); 
    afm.readCard(1);
    afm.setName_dish("turkse pizza");
    afm.updateCard();
            card=kaart.leesAlleKaarten1();
    System.out.println(kaart.leesAlleKaarten1());
}
public void start(){
    init();
}
public void stop(){

}
public void destroy(){

    }
```

}

my connection class which is in the same project but in a different class (not getting any errors from this):

```
public class Connectie {


    private String host= "localhost";
    private String user= "root";
    private String password="";
    private String databasenaam="kreta";

    java.sql.Connection connection;  

     public void displaySQLErrors( Exception e){
         String error;
         error="SQL foutmelding; "+ e.getMessage();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error, "foutmelding",+
                 JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

     }
     public Connectie(){
         try {

             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
         }
                     catch(Exception e){
             String error= "Niet mogelijk om de driver te laden";
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error, "error message",+
                     JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
             System.exit(1);
         }
         try{

             connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+ this.host+ "/"+this.databasenaam+"?user="+ this.user+"&password="+ this.password);

                             String succes= "there is a connectin with database";
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, succes,"succes",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

         }
         catch(Exception e){
             displaySQLErrors(e);                
         } 
     }      
}
```

This is what I get in the console:

```
1
did not update anything

all cards can not be read
all cards can not be read
[]
1
did not update anything
all cards can not be read
all cards can not be read
[]
```

I know my code isn't perfect seeing that I get error messages more than once. I just want to figure out Why retrieving and updating is not working. Cheers

When adding e.printStackTrace(); in my catch methods I get this really long error:

1
did not update anything

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM afhaalmenu' at line 1
All cards can not be read
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:941)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2470)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2546)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2504)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1370)
    at Kreta1$Afhaalmenu1.readAllCards(Kreta1.java:174)
    at Kreta1.init(Kreta1.java:256)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM afhaalmenu' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:941)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2470)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2546)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2504)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1370)
    at Kreta1$Afhaalmenu1.readALLCards(Kreta1.java:174)
    at Kreta1.init(Kreta1.java:257)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
all cards can not be read
[]
```

Comment: We will have a very difficulty trying to help you if you don't post the actual exception message and indicate which line throws it. Otherwise you're asking us to read minds, something we're not too good at.

Comment: Please edit your question and try to include this very pertinent information. You can edit this post by pressing the edit link immediately under your question tags, or by pressing [this same link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34867491/edit).

Comment: One obvious problem is that you have an extra comma (`,`) in your `INSERT` statement. Also, some of the SQL statements have semicolons which may cause problems, depending on the RDBMS. Finally, you should definitely use [`PreparedStatements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and parameterized SQL, instead of appending variables into SQL literals.

Comment: You're not catching and posting the exception stacktrace -- improve your catch blocks so that you see the full stacktrace by calling `e.printStackTrace()` within **every** catch block.

Comment: Ok. I'll take a look at the  extra  ( , ) in my insert statement. I did not delve in the PrepearedStatements yet but will definitely hit the study books to see if I can get more info on that type of statement. I have a previous program where I use semicolons in the same way. My RDBMS require the semicolons to work properly. Still I will have a look at that too.

Comment: good tip for now and the future to add e.printStackTrace() in all my try/catch methods. will try this too

Comment: In `getAllCards()`, you should change the query into `SELECT * FROM afhaalmenu`  (the `*` was missing).

Comment: `"Am I am fairly sure my SQL syntax is correct in my java code."` -- please never post such statements in your questions again, not unless you test first. Your exception stacktrace message is telling you in black and white with `MySQLSyntaxErrorException`, that this is emphatically not true.